# there is an error of htaccess configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, custom-error-pages

**Here is the link on the address bar:**

```
durnitibaz.com/news.php?n=ACC-raid-on-passport-office-3-brokers-jail-fine
```

**Here is the code of .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9] + )/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?n=$1 [L]
```

Now I cannot understand what is wrong with this code. Because this is not working when I try to access news from database like this url in address bar:

```
durnitibaz.com/news/ACC-raid-on-passport-office-3-brokers-jail-fine
```

This is Showing 404 error.

Comment: Missing the `/([0-9] + )/` part in your URL (And shouldn't that be `([0-9]+)`?)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `news/([0-9] + )` does not match `news/ACC` Remove that and looks like it'd be closer https://regex101.com/r/LrpaNt/1

Comment: So what can I do ? @user3783243

Comment: Is there suppose to be an integer value? If not remove that and it should work. Unrelated but `0-9a-zA-Z_` can also be simplified to `\w`. so `[-\w]` is the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`

Comment: Where I will put this ([0-9]+) code @brombeer

Comment: Instead of your `([0-9] + )` rule, which has spaces in it. Your url should look something like `durnitibaz.com/news/12345/ACC-raid-on-passport...`, most likely the articles `id` in your database ... which isn't in your original URL, so you might just leave it out: `^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)`. Use online tools like https://regex101.com/ to check your regex

Comment: Now the link is:
https://durnitibaz.com/news/99/ACC-raid-on-passport-office-3-brokers-jail-fine 
and the code is: 
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?n=$1 [L] 
It is showing still error.

Comment: If your rule is `news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)` the URL should be `.../news/ACC-raid-on-passport...`

Comment: @MymunaHossain You cant change URL and regex. Provide what the URL is and what the regex being used is. First regex was closer for the updated URL but need to remove spaces.

Comment: durnitibaz.com/news/Malaysia-Najib-alone-and-overwhelmed-by-betrayal
I used this code: RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ news.php?n=$1 [L]

Comment: @MymunaHossain That is similar to my answer below. However, you have included a trailing slash (not present in the example URL in your question) and you have omitted the end-of-string anchor (ie. `$`) so it will match literally anything. eg. `/news/ACC-raid-on-passport-office/anything/foo/bar/baz` - as explained in my answer (apart from a potential "duplicate content" issue, it opens your site up to malicious abuse).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^news/([0-9] + )/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?n=$1 [L]
> ```

There are many things wrong here:

- The regex, in this context (with unescaped spaces), in syntactically invalid.
- The regex is entirely wrong (even when "corrected") - it does not match the requested URL. There is no "id" (2nd path segment) in the requested URL. But this doesn't seem to be required for the target URL anyway.
- The second *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks whether the request maps to a `.php` file is never going to be successful for such a request, so the rule will also fail for this reason.
- The first *condition* that checks whether the request does not map to a directory would seem to be unnecessary.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)$ news.php?n=$1 [L]
```

This matches the example URL you posted. eg. `/news/ACC-raid-on-passport-office-3-brokers-jail-fine` and internally rewrites the request to `/news.php?n=ACC-raid-on-passport-office-3-brokers-jail-fine`.

The preceding `RewriteCond` directives are not required.

The shorthand character class `\w` is the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Note the end-of-string anchor (`$`) - this ensures you do not match too much (eg. actual files that contain a file extension) and result in a many-to-one rewrite.

Comment: Note in the comments the OP has stated the URL is different than provided in question. (Good answer though, answers question asked)

Comment: @user3783243 How so? With a numeric "id" as the second path segment? But that then doesn't match the original URL? (And the OP appears to have reverted back?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot solve this. 
Link: /news/Malaysia-Najib-alone-and-overwhelmed-by-betrayal
Code: RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)$ news.php?n=$1 [L]
Whats wrong ?

Comment: Is there any wrong ?
<a href="news/<?php echo $news_id; ?>" class="news_card" title="<?php echo $news_heading; ?>">

Comment: @MrWhite See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73592029/there-is-an-error-of-htaccess-configuration/73592159?noredirect=1#comment129955492_73592029, unclear what URL is to me. That has integer part of path... but here that is not present

Comment: @MymunaHossain That rule would certainly match the URL `/news/Malaysia-Najib-alone-and-overwhelmed-by-betrayal`. Do you have any other code in your `.htaccess` file? `<a href="news/<?php echo $news_id; ?>"` - Does this generate the stated URL? `$news_id` looks like an ID not a _title_?

Comment: @user3783243 OP has stated that the URL being tested is `/news/Malaysia-Najib-alone-and-overwhelmed-by-betrayal` (in the above comment). (?)

Comment: @MymunaHossain Are you sure your `.htaccess` file is actually doing anything (are `.htaccess` overrides enabled)? With your original code dump (with _spaces_ in the regex) you should have seen a 500 Internal Server Error (not a 404) on Apache, since that is wholly invalid. However, if on LiteSpeed then the error is likely suppressed.